# Scheduling an ec2-create-image cron job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I originally posted this on the AWS forums and didn't get much response.

I'm trying to schedule a twice daily image of a server, I'm using this entry in my crontab under the root user:

```
01 12,00 * * * /opt/aws/bin/ec2-create-image i-InstanceNameHere --region eu-west-1 --name `date +%s` --description "testing-imaging" --no-reboot -O ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS -W ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS
```

Running the command (with correct key information and instance name of course) manually successfully creates an image (but without the description), however when cronned nothing happens.

I've both had this command directly in crontab and have dropped the above command into a bash script which also pops out an entry in a file with a date stamp each time it runs, so I'm certain this isn't a cron issue.

Does anyone have any thoughts what could cause this to not work when scheduled?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Mike

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, as suspected, wasn't specifically do to with cron.

Off the back of error2007s's query for logs, I put everything into a bash script and pushed all output into a log file.

The issue was that when running through cron, most of the server variables needed weren't set, in the end I'm left with the below list definitions. These might be a bit overzelous, but in the end the process works.

```
#!/bin/sh

#Set required envionmental variables for ec2-create-image to run
export AWS_PATH=/opt/aws
export PATH=$PATH:$AWS_PATH/bin
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY=000000000000
export AWS_SECRET_KEY=000000000000000000000
export AWS_HOME=/opt/aws/apitools/ec2
export EC2_HOME=/opt/aws/apitools/ec2
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre

/opt/aws/bin/ec2-create-image i-123123123123123 --region eu-west-1 --name `date +%s` --description "testing-imaging" --no-reboot &>> backuplog.txt

echo "backup operation ran `date`" >> backuplog.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Cron runs on a 24 hour clock starting from 0 as midnight and 23 as 11 pm. As such you'd simply have to replace 12,0 with 0,12. Also just use single "0".

Comment: Thanks for this advice, I'd missed that.
The actual script I have in place (which outputs a datestamp to a file, so I know it's running) does seem to be getting kicked off at least once a day though

01 12,00 * * *  /root/backup-server.sh

I'm less focused at this point on the frequency and more on the fact that it doesn't actually kick the backup off.

Comment: So you are saying it runs just once a day or does not run at all?

Comment: Not at all, it seems less an issue about timing and more that when cron is involved in the execution of the task it doesn't actually run.

Comment: No errors I've yet to spot. There's no log created by the process, and there doesn't seem to be a verbose flag.. I've added a redirection of stdout and stderr to the end of the command in the batch script though, I've let you know if that turns up anything shortly.